# How to configure java logging.properties in spring-boot executable jar file

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I packaged my application as spring-boot executable jar file. I added a logging.properties in the root directory inside the jar file but it seems this file didn't have any impact on the application. How can I configure spring-boot executable jar logging?

Comment: Refer this link http://www.javabeat.net/spring-boot-logging/. If you are having a maven project, keep the log file in the resource folder and file name should be logback.xml

Comment: It is using xml format but I want to use properties. All the loggers in my app are from java.util.logging.Logger, whether I can use java logging.properties to configure my logging?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot uses Logback as default for logging. So you don't need any extra configuration for logging until you need to do any customized logging or other loggers like Log4j2.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    public class App 
    {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);    
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            logger.info("Hello Logger");
        }
    }
```

If you need to customize logging refer this like http://www.javabeat.net/spring-boot-logging/

I am not sure how to use the logger.properties. Why can't you use the logback.xml.

Comment: I have a lot of codes which are using java.util.logging. I have to change a lot places if I decided to use slf4j.

Comment: Are you trying to write all the logs in a separate file?

Comment: I want to write all logs in one file but separate by size.

Comment: Take a look at this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output

Comment: The document says "There are known classloading issues with Java Util Logging that cause problems when running from an ‘executable jar’. We recommend that you avoid it if at all possible." I tried many combinations but no luck.